# Probably a easy thing to do but how do I get javascript to only split if something is there, if not leave it as is

Tags: javascript

I'm using the following to get the title from a feed:

```
var posttitleGETcalendar = entry.title.$t;
var posttitleREMcalendar = posttitleGETcalendar.split("_");
var title =  posttitleREMcalendar[0] + "<small>" + posttitleREMcalendar[1] + "</small>";
```

What I'm trying to do is split the titles I get after underscore and add the tag small to the part after it.
Works great when underscore is there, but it shows the word *undefined* after last word if underscore is not on title.
Is there a way to use

```
if underscore is on title, do 
if not, leave it as is
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(/_/.test(posttitleGETcalendar)) {
    // posttitleGETcalendar.indexOf('_') != -1 would do too

    // do your stuff here
}
```

alternatively, you could use the `replace` method and skip the other auxilliar variables :

```
var title = entry.title.$t.replace('_', '<small>') + '</small>';
```

Comment: I like the replace answer, short and also does the job. I've tried it before but couldn't get it do work. Using your way, it works! Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the last line to:

```
var title = posttitleREMcalendar[0] 

if ( posttitleREMcalendar.length > 1 )
{
    title = title + "<small>" + posttitleREMcalendar[1] + "</small>";
}
```

This way you will only add the second part if it's present.